# Dropdown in navbar with fixed width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am building navbar with bootstap with fixed width, below is the code which I am using but the dropdown at the right side is not working

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="/">PROJECT</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul id="menu" class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contanct</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                <ul class="nav pull-right"> <!-- user-menu dropdown --> 
                    <li class="dropdown" id="user-menu">
                        <a href="#user-menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i style="opacity: 0.40;" class="icon-user icon-white">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;Anonymous
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li data-name="user-activity"><a href="#">Preferences</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> <!-- /user-menu dropdown --> 
            </div>
        </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
    </div>
```

I have included below css and js in sequential manner:

- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap-responsive.min.css
- jquery-1.4.1.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap-dropdown.js

Comment: We would really appreciate the working example, at least using something like jsFiddle

Comment: 2 things might be the source of the problem : jQuery 1.4 is not officially supported by the Twitter Bootstrap framework (it uses [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/),1.7+), and you must **not** include a plugin twice, considering that `bootstrap.min.js` contains all the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<div class="container">` and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/XXwnH/